Unable to capture logs using OpenTelemetry collector in Grafana Agent
I'm trying to setup logs with .NET and OpenTelemetry.
My goal is to send the logs to the Grafana Agent and then forward them to the collector
//Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

var otel = builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry();
otel.ConfigureResource(resource => resource
                          .AddService(builder.Environment.ApplicationName));

builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
   {
      options.IncludeScopes = true;
      options.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
      options.ParseStateValues = true;
      options.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
         {
            otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4318");
         });
   });

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", SendGreeting);
app.Run();

async Task<String> SendGreeting(ILogger<Program> logger)
   {
      logger.LogInformation("Test Log");
      return "Hello World!";
   }

Docker-compose.yml
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana-oss:latest
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    networks:
      - monitoring
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin

  grafana-agent:
    image: grafana/agent:latest
    ports:
      - "12345:12345"
    volumes:
      - ./grafana-agent.yaml:/etc/agent.yaml
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/agent.yaml"
    networks:
      - monitoring  

  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
    ports:
      - 1888:1888 # pprof extension
      - 8888:8888 # Prometheus metrics exposed by the Collector
      - 8889:8889 # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - 13133:13133 # health_check extension
      - 4317:4317 # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - 4318:4318 # OTLP http receiver
      - 55679:55679 # zpages extension
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
    networks:
      - monitoring
volumes:
  grafana-storage:

networks:
  monitoring:

grafana-agent.yml
server:
  log_level: info

logs:
  configs:
    - name: otel-logs
      positions:
        filename: /tmp/positions.yaml
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: otel-logs
          static_configs:
            - targets: ['localhost']
              labels:
                job: otel-logs
                __path__: /var/log/*.log
      clients:
        - url: http://otel-collector:4318

otel-collector-config.yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: info
service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: info
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging]

The logs reach the console (ConsoleExporter), but I don’t see them in the collector’s stdout logs
What am I doing wrong?

By default, the OtlpExporter using gRPC, but you're trying to using a HTTP receiver in the collector and port 4318. Either change the collector to open the gRPC receiver and use 4317, or set the protocol on the Exporter in the .NET code to HttpProtobuf

Also, the logging exporter is now deprecated in the collector, you should move to the debug exporter, and have an OTLP exporter that pushes the data to the grafana agent, or straight into the grafana stack services, the Grafana Agent isn't adding much in this setup, it's duplicating the effort of the collector.

Thank you for your response! I removed Grafana Agent from docker compose file, changed protocols in the otel-collector-config to grpc, exporters to debug, and the endpoint in my application to http://otel-collector:4317, but result is the same..

Are you sure the collector is working/running? Perhaps it's something you should discuss in the cncf slack instead, or possibly with the vendor?  The very least, please update the question to reflect the current state that isn't working.

turns out the problem was in the config for collector
proper configuration:
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed

service:
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [debug]

